# Cannot connect to a simple websocket server, created with Spring, through Chrome extension

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Here are three simple components of a WebSocket server, created on Spring

**Spring boot app**:

```
package test.andrew;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Websocket server configuration file**:

```
package test.andrew;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/name");
    }

}
```

**And a Socket text handler class**:

```
package test.andrew;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Pong"));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Connection established"));
    }
}
```

My problem is that the server doesn't work as it works, for example, when using plain old javax.websocket
I cannot establish a connection through the Smart Websocket Client Chrome extension and as a result, cannot proceed with sending a message to a wss.

I would be grateful for your help or advice!

Comment: Please include the package declarations in the mentioned classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum, done

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working? Do you see the endpoint being registered?

Comment: Yes, the endpoint is registered. What I expecte from the wss is to be able to connect and send message from a simple chrome client, that how it works with javax websockets

Comment: Any soluton for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by modifying WebSocketConfig Class to:

```
package test.andrew;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/name").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
}
```

Please note that .setAllowedOrigins("*") method is called. after allow origins, we can call this web socket url through chrome extension.

If you are using spring security then permit this url in spring security configuration file.